# Problems reading a text file in android java programming

Tags: java, android

I have some problems in reading text files.
I am trying to implement a method that can read from a text file.

The text file will be used in game.
Any help will be appreciated

I want to use this method for responding to the button I have in the layout.

The method will send an argument to createQuestions for reading a text file by line.

I want to make every line as questions and answers.

When I try it fails, and gives this error:
http://www.imageno.com/thumbs/20150416/0fx08sldrwxn.jpg

```
public void levelOne(View v)throws IOException{
Button buttond = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOne);
mQuestions = new ArrayList<Question>();
createQuestions("/raw/hogskoleprovetOne");

   }

  public void createQuestions(String hogskoleprovet) throws IOException{
    new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("hogskoleprovet"));

    InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("hogskoleprovet"));
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (input);
    //Lokala variabler för att användas i while loopen, för att man använder när man läser av

    String question;
    String answer;
    String answerOne;
    String answerTwo;
    String answerThree;
    String answerFour;

    while(sc.hasNext() == true){
        question = sc.nextLine();
        answer = sc.nextLine();
        answerOne = sc.nextLine();
        answerTwo = sc.nextLine();
        answerThree = sc.nextLine();
        answerFour = sc.nextLine();
        Question q = new Question (question, answer, answerOne, answerTwo, answerThree, answerFour);
        mQuestions.add(q);
    }
```

Comment: The image with the error is unreadable. Post the actual error text in the question.

Comment: (Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)

Comment: at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
     `at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372))

Comment: at            com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
             Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: hogskoleprovet
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:313)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:287)
            at

Comment: That was the error of the code

Comment: getAssets().open("hogskoleprovet") are you sure the quotes are what you intended? You don't use your variable but instead use its name as the value, seems weird to me.

Comment: How should I do? I am newbie

Answer (score 1):

You have this code:

```
public void createQuestions(String hogskoleprovet) throws IOException{
  InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("hogskoleprovet"));
```

Which means that whatever String you're passing as a parameter, you're not using it, you're reading the file "hogskoleprovet". I think what you mean is:

```
public void createQuestions(String hogskoleprovet) throws IOException{
  InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(hogskoleprovet));
```

Comment: Will the file in method levelOne be used then?

Comment: Well yes, that's what variables are for. I think you need to do a Java tutorial on basics before doing a full Android application if passing a variable to a method is something you're struggling with.